# Adding RAID drivers on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, raid

I am trying to get the IRST INTEL RAID drivers installed on an XP system.  I can only boot the XP system in IDE mode, but then I get the 'wrong hardware' message trying to install the RAID drivers.

I tried [the steps from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/211305/48078), but `iastorv` does not exist.

There is only iastor and the setting for START was already 0.  So is there something else I need to do in order to make this work? I really don't want to install a floppy disk.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and explain what you really want to do. Just copy/pasting the text from some answer without even providing the link to it isn't helpful at all. I found the link for you, but please make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: If reinstalling is an option, try putting the drivers on a floppy (or floppy-mode compatible flash drive) and press `F6` when the install process begins. Then you can select the drivers from the start, which is much easier than trying to add them later on.

Comment: If reinstalling is an option, do yourself a major favor and get a copy of [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/) and slipstream SP3 and your drivers onto a new CD.  You can do everything by hand, too, but nLite makes it trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that this is a RAID/IDE Port on a motherboard that can switch from a *SIMPLE* IDE port to a more complex RAID port?

If so, that's because the RAID controller doesn't exist until the motherboard is switched to RAID mode.
You can't switch to RAID mode because windows won't boot, because windows doesn't have the RAID drivers.

Swing it.

1. Install a PCI IDE card.
2. Install the Drivers for it.
3. Test it with CD/DVD drive connected to PCI card
4. Move the OS drive to the PCI-IDE card.
5. Test it with OS Drive
6. Switch motherboard to RAID mode.
7. Install RAID Drivers.
8. Test it with CD/DVD drive connected to RAID card.
9. Shutdown. Install OS drive to RAID card.

RAID Drivers installed